# already add permission but tips"Permission Denial" when I invoke a third-app

Tags: android, permissions, start-activity

I have two apps(named A-APP and B—APP), B-APP should invoke to start A-APP's activity,and the activity had added "android:permission" , I'm sure the B—APP is also add  in manifest.

the problem:
if a installed A-APP first,then install B-APP, it's no preblem running,but if i installed B-APP first,the app will throw exception "Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent",how can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set android:exported="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
android:name="com.a-app.MainActivity" 
android:exported="true">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" >
    </action>
</intent-filter>
```

If this doesn't help, can you post the full error and your AndroidManifest.xml files?